# Deleted comment that is still relevant

Tags: discussion, comments

I posted a comment on [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/49429/15469) answer which was the reason I didn't see that answer as correct. The comment was then deleted when a mod cleaned up the comments on that answer, but the answer hasn't changed and my criticism still applies.

Should I repost the comment, or leave it as is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Downvote, provide a better answer or improve your question, and move on.

Comments are not for arguing. The larger an argument gets, the more we are inclined to delete it (starting at "really quite" and moving upwards). If the answerer doesn't choose to improve their answer, arguing with them isn't useful. Instead, provide a better answer or better question such that your criticisms are channeled into a *useful* direction.

Comment: While I agree with this in principle, the deletion happened pretty fast and I suspect the answerer never saw the comment - I'd hate to downvote them for something they might not actually know about.

Comment: Provide a better answer then. You clearly *know* what a good answer should be, since you're trying to correct one.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that if I had a better answer, I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Then improve your *question* to be more clear.